# Не получается подключиться к серверу в MS SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server

Пишет, что не может подключиться. Но я не понимаю почему, сервер же запущен и работает. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `localhost\SQLEXPRESS`

Comment: Точно. Спасибо)